# Using jQuery UI's dialog("destroy") puts element in wrong place?

Tags: jquery, forms, dialog, popup

I have a big form with many parts. For each part, I want to add a small button "Popup as Dialog" which will convert that part to a dialog on-demand, and then (when closing the dialog) to return back to the form with the new inputs.

I am using jQuery UI's dialog() function. The pop-up parts works fine - the sub-form converts into a dialog. However, when I dialog("destroy") the sub-form, the element appears back, but at the end of the DOM document instead of the original location.

Is this a "feature" of dialog()? Anything to do about that?
Is there a better way to do this w/o using dialog()?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yeah, that's a 'feature'...haha...ran into it a while back. Here are a few 'gotchyas' and then a really hackity way of dealing with them (albeit effective if you're planning to have many subforms):

- When you create a dialog, jquery remembers it, and stores it in a separate div, then never puts it back (yep, the documentation lies in the sense that the element never goes back to where it was)
- My experience has been that if you mess with the hidden elements too much after that, you could break future dialog functionality. It's better to just create a new dialog box from new contents (especially if your application has many of these...coding each subform by hand will get tedious very quickly).
- If you can't reuse the div's, you'll have to clone them & rename them (which is what I do below)

Upon closing the dialog, the snippet below 'clones' the contents of the dialog, renames its id attribute, then appends the changed contents to a 'sub_form_container', thus generating a brand new dialog/form every time a user closes the dialog. Hope this helps!

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <link type="text/css" href="ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />  
  <script type="text/javascript" src="j.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src='ui.js'></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
                newDialogs(2); 
    });     
    function newDialogs(idCounter) {
      $('#d1').unbind().bind('click', function() {
        $('#d'+ idCounter.toString()).dialog({close: function(event, ui){
            var newSubForm = $('#d'+idCounter.toString()).clone();
                idCounter += 1;
                newSubForm.attr('id', 'd'+idCounter.toString()).attr('class', '').attr('style', '');
            $('#sub_form_container').append(newSubForm);
            newDialogs(idCounter);
            $('ui-dialog').remove()
          }
        });
      });
    }

  </script>

</head>
  <body>
    <h1>Element above</h1>
    <div>
      <div id='d1'>Activate dialog</div>
      <div id='sub_form_container'>
        <div id='d2'>Dialog content <input type='text' /></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <h1>Element below</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 14):

This worked for me:

- Clone the dialog
- Initialize the cloned dialog (so the original stays on the page)
- Remove the cloned dialog when I'm done with it

Code sample:

```
$('a.popup-modal').click(function(e){
    var $modal = $(this).closest('form').find('.modal').clone();
    $modal.dialog({
        autoOpen: true, 
        close: function(event, ui){
            $(this).remove();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This is awesome.  It's easier than the accepted answer's approach.  This is a really crappy "feature", they should really fix this crap up.

Comment: Very effective. Just make sure you don't close `div`s with `id`s.

Comment: How would you deal with modals with ids? Everything works unless I close it without triggering the duplication.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe add some code else it's hard to tell where/why your code might fail

You could just do it like this or similar

```
<input id="text" name="textname" type="text">
<input
  type="button"
  value="Pop me up"
  onclick="$('#text').clone().dialog({
    modal:true,
    close: function(event, ui) {
        $('#text').val(this.value);
    }
  });"
>
```

Check for a sample http://jsbin.com/ujema/